# IE 11 - screen font, print font with media type don't work

Tags: css, internet-explorer, media-queries, font-face, microsoft-edge

Our new site use some fonts from Google and we recently discover that there is a big problem to print a page with 2 fonts : OpenSansRegular and OpenSansSemibold. A sample page print on a HP LaserJet P3015 from an IE browser runs into 49.4c02 error. It seems (I googled a lot) that this problem occurs on most HP laserjet printers.
There are plenty of calls to these fonts in our style sheets, so rewrite them to make dependencies from media queries will be a hard work.
So I'm looking for an alternative : when I print a page, I want to replace these fonts by an Arial font.
I tried two ways :

1) call one single css. It contains this code :

```
@media screen {
    @font-face {
         font-family: OpenSansRegular;
         src: url(fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff) format("woff"), url(fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf) format("truetype"), url(fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#OpenSansRegular) format("svg");
         font-weight: normal;
         font-style: normal;
    }
}
@media print {
    @font-face {
        font-family: OpenSansRegular;
        src: local("Times New Roman");
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
}
```

Notice : on media "print" I use the local font "Times New Roman" and not the target "Arial" because it's more easy to check the differences and see if it's work !

**Results**

- OK with Firefox, Chrome, Opera : OpenSansRegular is used on the
  screen and "Times New Roman" on the print preview
- KO with IE, Edge : OpenSansRegular is not loaded, so Arial is used. It seems IE and Edge
  don't support @font-face in @media.

2) use media="print" on the link to load the alternate font :

```
<link href="screen_font.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="print_font.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

screen_font.css :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: OpenSansRegular;
    src: url(fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff) format("woff"), url(fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf) format("truetype"), url(fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#OpenSansRegular) format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

print_font.css :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: OpenSansRegular;
    src: local("Times New Roman");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

**Results**

- OK with Firefox, Chrome, Opera : OpenSansRegular is used on the screen and "Times New Roman" on the print preview
- KO with IE, Edge, "Times New Roman" is used on screen and print media. It seems it's the last font's declaration which is used whatever the media defined.

Here a zip file with the sample code : [zip file](http://dl.free.fr/ni6R59oGl)

No more idea on my side. Any help will be appreciated...

Thanks to "Coop", we have added these media queries :

```
//IE10 and 11 hack
@media print and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    body * { font-family :Arial, sans-serif ; }
}
/* Windows 10 Edge Browser */
@media print and @supports (-ms-accelerator:true) {
    body * { font-family :Arial, sans-serif ; } 
}
```

We target IE and of course Microsoft Edge.

Comment: If you Google this issue, you'll find a lot info in it, and even solutions. ("font face inside media queries") As quite often, Microsoft implements the spec truthfully: [in CSS2.1 @ rules are not allowed inside media queries and are therefore ignored](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html#at-media-rule). I've been looking for the same info in CSS3, but I can't seem to find it. It's possible that this restriction has been lifted in CSS3.

Comment: I had google a lot and found the same information.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may indeed run into issues trying to load `@font-face` inside `@media` queries. The way I expect most people would do this would be to load any fonts outside of media queries so they're ready to use. Then use media queries to apply the correct font. For example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: OpenSansRegular;
  src: url(fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff) format("woff"), url(fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf) format("truetype"), url(fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#OpenSansRegular) format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }

@media screen {
  body { font-family: OpenSansRegular; }
}

@media print {
  body { font-family: "Times New Roman"; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote in my post : "There are plenty of calls to these fonts in our style sheets, so rewrite them to make dependencies from media queries will be a hard work. So I'm looking for an alternative..."

Comment: I see. Well you could try using a command like `body * { font-family: "Times New Roman"; }` inside the print media query which would force all elements to use Times New Roman for print. Or alternatively (and probably not a suitable answer here) I would personally write a stylesheet like this with SASS so you can update individual variables rather than fonts in multiple places